# Using a single physical test machine for multiple team projects

Tags: testing, tfs, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

My situation is this: I have multiple rather small winforms projects that I'm creating coded UI tests for. I have one physical machine availble for running said UI tests, and each project needs to run the tests quite rarely, so one machine is enough.

I got the tests running on a single project (using MTM, created test cases, then on VS side I used the associated automation -thing, created a LabDefaultProcess and mapped them to the test suite) and this works exactly as I wanted.

The problem comes when I try using the same testing machine for another team project. I am unable to add the environment from MTM Lab Management because it says the chosen environment is already in use.

So is there really such a limitation (meaning that I would have to combine all my projects to a single team project to get over it), or is there a more sophicisticated way of doing this?

On the single computer available for testing I have the test controller and test agent installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment you have created is bound to your team project. This is a requirement within Lab Management where your machine is not a very loosely coupled entity for reuse.

The one way you could work around this is by customizing your build template. eg. custom build template with a parameter that specifies which project you want to work with. This fires off a build on that specific project's build definition and then copies the drop to your drop folder for further use.

Issues here will be that all your test results will be reported against this single project and not really against the original project. Plus you need to maintain the template yourself.

Comment: So it's basically the same as moving all the projects into a single team project. Meh, seem really silly but I guess it'll just have to do. Thanks for the reply.